# encoding with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, encoding, iis-7, url-rewriting

To access a page in my website I use this rule

```
^/map/(.+)\-([0-9]{1,5})/map-.+\-street\-([a-z])\.html$
```

The link I use is `www.mydomain.com/map/neus%e4%df-86/map-neus%e4%df-street-a.html`. 
 When I'll chekc the IIS7 rewrite log the link is transformed to 
 `/map/neusä߆/map-neusäß-street-a.html`, and of course I got a 404 error.

So, my question is, why is `neus%e4%df-86` transormed to `neusä߆`
 instead of `neustäß` 
(P.S. the page-s encoding is charset=iso-8859-1)

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the solution. The [NE] flag was not set at the end of the rule. Related to the Helicon's documentation, `"NE: Don't escape output. By default ISAPI_Rewrite will encode all non-ANSI characters as %xx hex codes in output."` This way the link remains unencoded.